# React query isLoading and isFetching Issue when localStorage value is updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am creating a cart page for an ecommerce site.

I am using redux for state management and react-query for data management. I am new in redux and react-query. I am facing some problem while updating localStorage.

Redux initially setting cartItem from localStorage. But the problem occurs when I try to remove a item from the cart. When I click on remove button react-query trigger isLoading. I try to use isFetching but it did the same. How can I fix that?

**Cart Page**

```
const CartPage = () => {
  const { cartItems } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cartItems.length > 0) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [cartItems]);

  const ids = cartItems.map((item) => item.id);

  const {
    data: cartData,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
    status,
    isFetching
  } = useQuery(["cart", ids], () => getCartItems(ids), {
    staleTime: Infinity
  });


  if (loading || isLoading) {
    console.log("Fetching data...");
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }


  return (
      <div className="container">
        {
          !cartItems.length
            ? <div className="cart-empty">
              <h2 className="cart-empty__title">Your cart is empty</h2>
              <Link href="/shop" className="btn btn-primary">Go To Shop</Link>
            </div>
            : <div>
                <div className="cart-details-main-block" id="dynamic-cart">
                {Children.toArray(
                  cartData.map((item) => {
                    return <CartProduct {...item} />;
                  })
                )}
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**CartProduct**

```
export default function CartProduct({ _id, title, price, image }) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // remove item from cart and update the cart ui 

  const handleRemoveFromCart = (id) => {
    dispatch(removeItemFromCart({ id }));
  }

  return (
    <div className="cart-product cart-product--main">
      {/* .product-quantity-block starts */}
      <div className="total-block pl-7 pl-xs-0">
        <div className="total-block-inner">
          <h3 className="price-text">
            $140
          </h3>
          <button onClick={() => handleRemoveFromCart(_id)}>
            &#10006;
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**cartSlice**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const CART_KEY = 'cart';

// Load cart data from local storage
const loadCartFromStorage = () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const cartData = localStorage.getItem(CART_KEY);
    if (cartData) {
      return JSON.parse(cartData);
    }
  }
  return { cartItems: [] };
};

// Save cart data to local storage
const saveCartToStorage = (cartData) => {

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {

    localStorage.setItem(CART_KEY, JSON.stringify(cartData));
  }
};

// Define the cart slice
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: loadCartFromStorage(),
  reducers: {
    addItemToCart: (state, action) => {
      // Check if the item already exists in the cart

      const itemIndex = state.cartItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);

      if (itemIndex >= 0) {
        // If the item already exists, update the quantity
        state.cartItems[itemIndex].quantity += action.payload.quantity;

      } else {
        // If the item doesn't exist, add it to the cart
        state.cartItems.push(action.payload);

      }
      // Save the cart data to local storage
      saveCartToStorage(state);
    },
    removeItemFromCart: (state, action) => {

      // Remove the item from the cart
      state.cartItems = state.cartItems.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);

      // Save the cart data to local storage
      saveCartToStorage(state);
    },
  },
});

// Export the actions
export const { addItemToCart, removeItemFromCart } = cartSlice.actions;

// Export the reducer
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I click on remove button react-query trigger isLoading

From a `useQuery` perspective, you have all ids in the QueryKey, because they are used in the QueryFunction. That is correct, but it also means that every time the ids change, you get a new cache entry. This means you'll get a loading state again because for that cache entry, there is no data yet.

There are multiple ways to solve that issue, the easiest being to add `keepPreviousData: true`:

```
useQuery(["cart", ids], () => getCartItems(ids), {
  staleTime: Infinity,
  keepPreviousData: true
});
```

this will make sure data is still displayed as-is while you're transitioning between QueryKeys.